# Airflow AD/LDAP superuser_filter versus data_profiler_filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap, airflow

I'm in the process of configuring my Admin access to Airflow but I'm confused about the difference between the **superuser_filter** and the **data_profiler_filter**.

1. If I do not set either of these two values then everyone on my AD/LDAP is able to log into Airflow and view/use all of the Admin features. This is the expected default behavior that's working.
2. If I only set the **superuser_filter** then Admin's can view the Admin button but only the *Pools*, *Configuration*, *Users*, *Connections*, and *XComs* features appear (Not the *Variables* feature).
3. If I only set the **data_profiler_filter** then Admin's can view the Admin button but only the *Variables* feature appears.
4. If I set **both** the superuser_filter and the data_profiler_filter (to the same admin group value 
   e.g., 
   `superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=ADMINTEAM,OU=SvcAccts,DC=us,DC=ae,DC=com
   data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=ADMINTEAM,OU=SvcAccts,DC=us,DC=ae,DC=com`) then no one in my AD/LDAP (including Admins) are able to view the Admin button; I'm wondering if this is because I need two separate distinct groups for these two filter's values and not one group value for both?

Can someone please help me distinguish these two values and how they should be set? Also, to expand on my comment in number four above [the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ldap) uses two different group values for these two filters (**airflow-super-user** and **airflow-data-profilers**), does that mean you cannot use the same group value for the two filters? E.g., I have one Airflow Admin group (*ADMINTEAM*) and I'd like to be able to use it for both values if that's possible but that doesn't seem to work, it seems like it wants two different group values.

**Airflow.cfg LDAP Configuration**

```
[ldap]
# set a connection without encryption: uri = ldap://<your.ldap.server>:<port>
uri = ldap://123.456.789:123
user_filter = objectclass=*
# in case of Active Directory you would use: user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
# group_member_attr should be set accordingly with *_filter
# eg :
#     group_member_attr = groupMembership
#     superuser_filter = groupMembership=CN=airflow-super-users...

superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=ADMINTEAM,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=ADMINTEAM,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com

group_member_attr = member
group_name_attr = CN
group_filter = objectclass=group
bind_user = CN=blah,OU=foo,DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
bind_password = yahoo
basedn = DC=us,DC=bar,DC=com
# Set search_scope to one of them:  BASE, LEVEL , SUBTREE
# Set search_scope to SUBTREE if using Active Directory, and not specifying an Organizational Unit
search_scope = SUBTREE
```

Comment: To point #4 I expected it to OR the results of #2 and #3.  I would think you'd be able to use the same group for both filters, but it's a little beyond my knowledge of the Airflow LDAP integration so far.  Can you try posting this one to the Airflow dev mailing list (could link back to this question) to see if anyone there can provide more specific help.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?